# What are the conventions for declaring a UITabBarController in mainwindow.xib?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a mainwindow.xib file with a `UITabBarController` as the base view controller of the app.  So inside the UITabBarController I've added about 10 sub `UIViewController` objects as tabs.  Most of them are just a `UITableViewController` subclass or a `UINavigationController` containing a `UITableViewController` subclass.

In this design, each `UIViewController` is fully loaded on app startup, including calling the `viewDidLoad` method of each view controller.  Is there any way to get around that?  Since the view controllers are just UITableViewControllers with no other outlets, it seems excessive to create a NIB for each tab (which I assume would allow the viewDidLoad to only get called when the user first switches to the tab?  Or am I wrong on that?)

Anyway, my question mainly, is: how is it *conventionally* done?  If you have 10 different view controllers on one `UITabBarController`, do you put them all in mainwindow.xib?  If so, should each have its own NIB, and if not, where do you put them, and how do you add them to the tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to define the UIViewController views in a different xib file for each view - the reason they all get instantiated is that when the xib loads, all objects held in the xib load - and that means all your views and view controllers since you have defined them there.

In MainWindow.xib where you have the tab bar defined, you can still set within each tab the view controller type that will be called and also the XIB file to use for that type (create a new project with the "TabBar application" template and the second default view will be like this).

Then as you press tabs the view controllers will be instantiated from the different XIB files you have defined.

Note that this means if you are using IB to add buttons to the navigation bar, you have to do that back in the TabBar xib and not in the xib you use to define the view.  You can still link actions to the view controller definition within the tab.

Comment: Handily enough, I was able to just create one NIB file and reference the same one for each tab, since they are pretty much just a plain ol' UITableViews, with the code being what differentiates them.

Answer (score 0):

The way Apple suggests doing it for pure NIB files is how you say: [Each sub-view in its own NIB file](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW14).

Instead of doing this, I would [create the UITabBarController programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW15). That way you can define all your simple views in code, and still [load complex views from NIB files](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW33).

Personally, I prefer creating as many of my views programatically as possible. The compiled code has a smaller footprint than the NIB files and I feel like I have more control. I mostly use Interface Builder to mock up applications.